# Allowing users to input several different types of DateTime formats

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I have an application where I allow users to input different DateTime formats. So they could add into a list something like 'MM/dd/yyyy' or 'MM/DD/YYYY' etc, etc. Is there a way for me to check their input against a dataset of different of acceptable formats? Id like to display an error to them if they input a format which is not accepted by their culture.

I've seen posts here where you can use the DateTime [TryParse or TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx), but those seem to check the syntax of a string of an actual date like say '01/20/2016' as opposed to checking the actual format type as I describe above.

I've seen many posts where I can do something like :

```
var formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd" };
```

And then use that format array as a check against an actual date, but can I check against a user input of the actual format type? Also I would rather not have to create a list myself of acceptable formats, but would rather use some type of already existing dictionary of acceptable formats to check against. I have looked around but have come up short handed in my pursuit. If there is some documentation out there or some method that could help me, please point me in the correct direction so that I can investigate it. Thanks.

Comment: `TryParseExact` is exactly what you want - the second argument to [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx) is an array of format strings. Note that it's inherently problematic to accept dd/MM/yyyy and MM/dd/yyyy though... consider what 01/02/2016 should mean.

Comment: Didn't even realize there was an overload that took an array of formats. Sometimes I'm surprised :)

Comment: You may want to use TryParse first which accepts a large number of different formats.  If TryParse Fails then use you own array of custom formats.

Comment: Why not give your users a control that is designed for picking dates, say `DateTimePicker`?  Then there is no need to worry about date formats.